# Views 3 doesn't recognize a declared handler. Why not?

Tags: 7, views

In modules/addressfield/addressfield.module I have:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function addressfield_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'addressfield') . '/views',
  );
}
```

and

```
/**
*  Implements hook_field_views_data_alter
* 
* @param mixed $result
* @param mixed $field
*/
function addressfield_field_views_data_alter (&$result, $field) {
  if (array_key_exists('field_data_field_address', $result)) {
    $result['field_data_field_address']['field_address_country'] += array(
      'title' => t('Country'),
      'help' => t('The Country name of the field'),
      'field' => array(
        'handler' => 'addressfield_views_handler_field_country',
        'click sortable' => TRUE,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In modules/addressfield/views/addressfield.views.inc:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_handlers().
 */
function addressfield_views_handlers() {
  return array(
    'info' => array(
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'addressfield') . '/views',
    ),
    'handlers' => array(
      'addressfield_views_handler_field_country' => array(
        'parent' => 'views_handler_field',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

This file doesn't get triggered in the debugger when I clear the cache. I don't understand this.

The handler is in modules/addressfield/views/addressfield_views_handler_field_country.inc which I took from the location module:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Country field handler.
 */

class addressfield_views_handler_field_country extends views_handler_field {

  function option_definition() {
    $options = parent::option_definition();
    $options['style'] = array('default' => 'name');
    return $options;
  }

  function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
    parent::options_form($form, $form_state);
    $form['style'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Display style'),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => array('name' => t('Country name'), 'code' => t('Country code')),
      '#default_value' => $this->options['style'],
    );
  }

  function render($values) {
      return check_plain(strtoupper($values->{$this->field_alias}));
  }
}
```

Any advice on how to get this to work would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Just a general comment. The current api version of views itself is '3.0-alpha1', so you can't use 3. You should share your copy of views, because it's from the future ;)

Comment: I had this problem it showed in the logs as "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in views_get_handler()"  sticking here so if someone searches for that they will find this helpful page.

Comment: Just a tip: execute "drush vd" once ... this will show you some debug messages if handlers are missing somehow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Which core version? In Drupal 7, hook_views_handlers() is gone, add your files to your .info file instead.

```
files[]=views/addressfield_views_handler_field_country.inc
```

Comment: It actually says so in the Views advanced help pages (page "Upgrading to Drupal 7 (API)")

Comment: You'd think Drupal could emit a watchdog warning that it won't load the file because it's not whitelisted.  I should invoice Dries for the hours I've spent chasing this down.

Comment: In addition to the .inc file I also had to include my MYMODULE.views.inc file in my .info file.  Any reason why that might be?  If I don't include it then my views plugin is not detected.