# Views & custom exposed filters : where do I start?

Tags: views

I've got this module which makes an additional field available when you base the view on **Users**. The field is made available through `hook_views_data()`.

I've created a filter for this field, and it should be exposed to users. However, what I would really like to do is to create a custom filter. That is, a very custom form with some specialised options which the user can choose between.

How do I go about doing this?  How do I tell Views that I've got this custom exposed filter. I know `hook_views_plugins` has something to do with this, but I can't find any place which describes the general picture of how things interact. Does anyone have any experience with this; and how things work together and which pieces I need to solve the "puzzle"?

Any input appreciated!

Comment: Also, see this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26376/where-can-i-learn-about-how-to-create-a-custom-exposed-filter-for-views-3-and-d7

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best place to start is to look at the way some other module is doing it. Or how views itself does it for some core module :) (i.e. [taxonomy](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!modules!taxonomy.views.inc/function/taxonomy_views_data/7) or [user](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!modules!user.views.inc/function/user_views_data/7).
There is at least 3 things you have to do :

1. tell views you have something for it
2. provide it :)
3. tell drupal to load it

the telling can be done by implementing :

- [hook_views_data](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) in case you define an entire field, or
- hook_field_views_data_views_data_alter (no doc if i get it right) if you want to change someone elses field filtering

create a directory views, place a file called your_module.views.inc in it and put the hooks there.

then create a file with a class that will extend the filter

and include that file in the modules info file

dont forget to refresh cache and that should be it :)